# treemap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path' in plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly

```
statewise_cases["Country"] = "Country"
print(statewise_cases)
fig = px.treemap(statewise_cases, path = ['Country', 'State'], values='Deaths')
fig.show()
```

Comment: You've included some code in your question, and that's cool. Would you consider including your `imports` and a sample of your dataset? As your question now stands, anyone trying to solve your problem is going to spend more time reproducing your issue rather than answering your question.

Comment: Please, paste your import -lines.

Answer (score 7):

Upgrading `plotly` fixed this issue for me: `pip install --upgrade plotly`. My previous version was 4.4.1, and I upgraded to 4.7.1. Perhaps this is a problem with older versions of `plotly`.

(Just in case you're interested in checking your `plotly` version: `px.__version__` doesn't work because `plotly` does not have a `__version__` property. I used `pip freeze` to list all my packages and their versions, and checked the `plotly` version from there).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the version of Plotly, by updating it will be solved.

Google Colab:

!pip install --upgrade plotly

Windows:

pip install --upgrade plotly

Linux:

pip3 install --upgrade plotly

Answer (score 0):

`plotly.graph_objects.Treemap` does not have keyword argument `path`. This is what the error message is saying. It has `pathbar` though but it should should be dict.

`plotly.express.treemap` on other hand has path as as an argument.

My best bet is that you have imported another library you think you are using.